# Chrome Extension properly gets current URL and title, except on Youtube

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I made this extension as an exercise in passing current page parameters onto another script later down the road. Using chrome.tabs.getSelected, I can retrieve the url and title of almost any page that I navigate to...except Youtube. For some reason, the alert box shows the current URL, but the previous title.

I have tried delaying the retrieval of the title, but that has produced other problems like multiple alerts or "undefined" values.

**background.js**

```
chrome.webNavigation.onHistoryStateUpdated.addListener(function(details) {
    chrome.tabs.getSelected(null,function(tab) { // null defaults to current window
        if(typeof chrome._LAST_RUN === 'undefined' || notRunWithinTheLastSecond(details.timeStamp)){
            // Fires only when details.url === currentTab.url
            chrome._LAST_RUN = details.timeStamp;
                    var myurl = tab.url;
                    var mytitle = tab.title;
                    zurl = myurl + "\r\n" + "\r\n" + mytitle;
                    alert(zurl);
        }
    });
});
const notRunWithinTheLastSecond = (dt) => {
    const diff = dt - chrome._LAST_RUN
    if (diff < 2000){
      return false
    } else {
      return true
    }
  }
```

**manifest.json**

```
"permissions"       : [ 
    "tabs",
    "webNavigation"
]
```

Comment: The title is updated [much] later, after history state is changed, and it can take a long time. Use chrome.tabs.onUpdated instead of webNavigation to get notified both for the title and the url.

Comment: that was what I used originally, but it produced several alerts. Essentially anytime something got updated (which seems to be a lot on Youtube), another alert would be generated. Any way to do that and keep it limited to one result (popup)?

Comment: The title is reported separately. You can skip the alert for the url on youtube, wait for the title, then report both.

Answer (score 0):

Youtube likes to load subsequent pages dynamically (fetch JSON object and parsing on the client) and sets title very late.

It gets worse, if you override document.title property

```
let actualTitle = document.title;

Object.defineProperty(document, 'title', {
    set: function (newValue) {
         console.log(newValue);
         actualTitle = newValue;
    },

    get: function () {
        return actualTitle;
    }
});
```

you will notice Youtube likes to set title to nonsensical values ("YouTube", "", or raw URL) while loading any page, this results in Chrome history randomly not being able to remember some youtube link Titles https://www.reddit.com/r/youtube/comments/7e5j3f/youtube_video_titles_not_appearing_anymore_in/

> When you open YouTube for the first time, the Chrome history link simply shows "YouTube". Any video you click on in that tab will show the video title in the Chrome history link. If you open a video from that tab in a new tab or window, it won't show the video title in the Chrome History link.

> If you want the title of that video to show in the Chrome history link, you have to do a search for that video in the new window or tab you just opened and then click on its link. Then the video title will show in the Chrome history link.

I could even risk assuming Google is doing this as a dark pattern to force users into keeping Youtube History tracking turned on. You cant rely on your User Agent History search when random number of entries is saved under "Youtube" title :/

You might have to resort to intercepting title changes and ignoring "YouTube", "", or raw URL.